# Codeception Recorder is disabled, no available modules

Tags: php, codeception

In order to record my tests I run codeception with this command

```
codecept --ext Recorder
```

However I can't manage to record anything. Does one see what I'm doing wrong?

```
Codeception Recorder is disabled, no available modules:
```

[image: Screenshot]

gravityflow/codeception.dist.yml
[image: Screenshot]

gravityflow/plugin/tests/acceptance-tests/acceptance.suite.yml:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You're using the WordPress module, *WPWebDriver*. You need to tell *recorder* it's active. Put this in your main *codeception.yml* file:

```
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
        - Codeception\Extension\Recorder
    config:
        Codeception\Extension\Recorder:
            delete_successful: false
            module: WPWebDriver
```